# Reconstruct a recursively prime-encoded integer

Tags: code-golf, math, primes, ragged-list

**Recursively prime-encoded integers**

Consider \$11681169775023850 = 2 \times 5 \times 5 \times 42239 \times 5530987843\$. This isn't a nice prime factorisation, as \$42239\$ and \$5530987843\$ make it difficult to store this factorisation in a small manner. Being primes, we can't then factorise them, but we can factorise \$p - 1\$, which is guaranteed to not be prime (ignoring \$p = 3\$). by doing this we get:

- \$42239 \to 42238 = 2 \times 7 \times 7 \times 431\$
- \$5530987843 \to 5530987842 = 2 \times 3 \times 17 \times 54225371\$

This helps, but \$431\$ and \$54225371\$ are still pesky, so we run the same procedure (prime factorising their decrement). Just to be safe, we'll also do it with \$17\$ so that we can only have single digit primes (\$2,3,5,7\$) in the final result. This eventually results in:

```
[2, 5, 5, [2, 7, 7, [2, 5, [2, 3, 7]]], [2, 3, [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 5, [2, 2, 2, 5], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, [2, 2, [2, 2, 2, 3, [2, 3, 7]]]]]]]
```

representing \$11681169775023850\$. [This](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7ZzxqWpP1qGGOgq6dwqOGuQ93tjzcOfvhzlVcOofb0g63P2qYeXi@it2hhUBllv///zc0NLMAYktzc1MDI2MLUwMA) is a program that shows the steps of decomposition of the input, and [this](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW5rCo4aZh@erKBzaqWBnqWL/qGkN1@H2o5Me7pzx//9/Q0MzCyC2NDc3NTAytjA1AAA) is a program which decomposes a given integer.

The representations for the integers from 2 to 25 are:

```
 2 [2]
 3 [3]
 4 [2, 2]
 5 [5]
 6 [2, 3]
 7 [7]
 8 [2, 2, 2]
 9 [3, 3]
10 [2, 5]
11 [[2, 5]]
12 [2, 2, 3]
13 [[2, 2, 3]]
14 [2, 7]
15 [3, 5]
16 [2, 2, 2, 2]
17 [[2, 2, 2, 2]]
18 [2, 3, 3]
19 [[2, 3, 3]]
20 [2, 2, 5]
21 [3, 7]
22 [2, [2, 5]]
23 [[2, [2, 5]]]
24 [2, 2, 2, 3]
25 [5, 5]
```

For example, for `[2, [2, 5]]`, we first multiply the inner list and increment to get `[2, 11]`. From here, we just multiply, resulting in the final output of `22`

---

You are to take the representation of a recursively prime-encoded integer and output the original integer.

The input will be a jagged list, where each element is either a single digit prime (\$2,3,5,7\$) or a list where the same rule applies. The input will never contain empty lists, and will never be empty.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins

### Test cases

```
[2, 2, 2, 5] -> 40
[[2, 2, 3]] -> 13
[[2, 3, 5]] -> 31
[3] -> 3
[2, 3, 3, 5] -> 90
[2, [2, [2, 5]]] -> 46
[[2, 5]] -> 11
[[2, 2, 7, [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 7]]] -> 9437
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5] -> 480
[2, 2, 2, 7, [2, 2, 2, 2]] -> 952
[2, [2, 2, 3, 7, [2, 3, 3]]] -> 3194
[2, 3, 3, [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 7]] -> 8082
[5, [2, 2, 7], [2, [2, [2, 5]]]] -> 6815
[5, [2, [2, 2, [2, 2, 2, 5], [2, [2, 5, 5, 5]]]]] -> 824935
[3, 3, [2, 2, 3, 3], [2, 7, [2, [2, 2, 2, 5]]]] -> 387279
[7, [2, 2, 5, 5], [2, 3, 5, [2, 3, 7]]] -> 912737
[[2, [2, [2, 5, [2, 2, 3]], [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 7]]]] -> 528719
[2, 2, 2, 2, 7, [2, 5], [2, 2, [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]]] -> 952336
[2, 3, 3, [2, 3, 5], [2, 5, 5, [2, 2, 7]]] -> 809658
[[2, 2, 2, 3, [2, 2, [2, 3, 7]]], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, [2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 7, [2, 3, 3, 7]], [2, 5, [2, 2, 2, [2, 5]], [2, [2, 2, [2, 2, 3]]]]]] -> 3511306351619449
[5, 7, 7, [2, 3, [2, 5], [2, [2, 2, 2, 5]]], [2, 2, 2, 7, [2, [2, [2, 2, 2, [2, 5]]]], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, [2, 5, [2, 3, [2, 2, 2, 2]]]]]] -> 8013135306533035
[2, 3, 3, [2, 2, 2, 3, 3], [2, 3, [2, [2, 5]]], [2, 3, [2, 2, 3, [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3], [2, [2, 5, 7, 7]], [2, 2, [2, 5], [2, 2, [2, 2, 3]]]]]] -> 2925382459116618
```

Comment: This is very similar to jan Misali's proposed way of naming bases: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7OEF3JD-jYo

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 42 bytes

*Thanks to @tsh for suggesting a 2-byte improvement*

```python
f=lambda x=1,*a:x<2or-(x*-1or~f(*x))*f(*a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVPLboMwELzzFb4VoqRivRjbUemPIFRRNVEi5YFS0qSX/npqbOMHpZIjYntndnd23H33u/OJPh7b6tAe3z9acq9guWjX9xd6vqzS@2IF58vPNl3cs2yhPm32uO32hw2BdUL2p25Jzte@IxU5tl26@WoPS3Jpb2/q5tqn2fNnd9j36RNZvZKnLEtId9mfeqJ4VEBGqkqjHzVdErNYM4QWeVLbM2z0CaA5wSFEnyAkNZp/ib3BES9zfTT@FMLQlobEMgC4LNwEuqWYuAXJAnkSXdIgUyHy4DKmsXhGXTGW2WxQN2d7kUXQxDQb1dUMgSIXio25EN74LsdOdWApgLlAGxyqHEDMakakoIVEhY1K0bWaHY84w5woOOUyqb0KzKdCvasn2gLlg7pRCz5p0/wdi0VrOKOCg4yHw0chZtr2PI2bDWI5UR49moXljEWLXJZMOOvQUKegv/nEQXOe2PtBQ6c6@NnOjRMbNzpkAJiX6lMqQxVSG4CHCerJ8P0Ewz2PTRWVMNeY145Fmdw7cN7KAQGZqpEh5oPLZjwfeA1jZ0/JZ54Kxs7mgaD0P2cEClJJGaoXwCRAWYL4BQ)

`-(x*-1or~f(*x))` computes for a given element, its decoded value. If `x` is an integer, the `or` will short circuit, resulting in `x` as the value. If it is a list, `x*-1` will return an empty list, and the result becomes a recursive call on `x`: `-~f(*x)`.

This result is then multiplied by the rest of the elements through recursion: `f(*a)`. Finally, the default `x=1` argument assists in the terminating condition of `x<2`.

Comment: Python 3, 43 bytes: `f=lambda x=1,*a:x==1or-(x*-1or~f(*x))*f(*a)`

Comment: In case anybody is wondering about @tsh's modification: The original code relies on the `<` operator allowing comparisons between `list` and `int`.  This is allowed in Python 2, but not in Python 3.

Answer (score 8):

## [yuno](https://github.com/hyper-neutrino/yuno), 5 bytes

```
ᴘ’)υ‘
```

[Try it online!](https://yuno.hyper-neutrino.xyz/#WyIiLCLhtJjigJkpz4XigJgiLCIiLCIiLCIiLFsiWzIsIDMsIDMsIFsyLCAyLCAyLCAzLCAzXSwgWzIsIDMsIFsyLCBbMiwgNV1dXSwgWzIsIDMsIFsyLCAyLCAzLCBbMiwgMiwgMiwgMiwgMiwgM10sIFsyLCBbMiwgNSwgNywgN11dLCBbMiwgMiwgWzIsIDVdLCBbMiwgMiwgWzIsIDIsIDNdXV1dXV0iXV0=)

```
(ᴘ’)υ‘    Main Link
(  )υ     Deep Recurse; on each sub-list and recursively, call
 ᴘ        - Product
  ’       - Increment
     ‘   Decrement
```

I've had the idea for `υ` from ever since I first started drafting yuno, but this adverb was implemented after this challenge.

**Old version**

## [yuno](https://github.com/hyper-neutrino/yuno), 7 bytes

```
ɫ’)ᴅ?Ͼᴘ
```

[Try it online!](https://yuno.hyper-neutrino.xyz/#WyIiLCLJq+KAmSnhtIU/z77htJgiLCIiLCIiLCIiLFsiWzIsIDMsIDMsIFsyLCAyLCAyLCAzLCAzXSwgWzIsIDMsIFsyLCBbMiwgNV1dXSwgWzIsIDMsIFsyLCAyLCAzLCBbMiwgMiwgMiwgMiwgMiwgM10sIFsyLCBbMiwgNSwgNywgN11dLCBbMiwgMiwgWzIsIDVdLCBbMiwgMiwgWzIsIDIsIDNdXV1dXV0iXV0=)

Expect this to get shorter later once I implement more adverbs.

For now, this is the same approach as my Jelly solution.

```
(ɫ’)ᴅ?Ͼᴘ    Main Link
      Ͼ     For each item
     ?      - If
    ᴅ         - It has depth (it is a list and not just a single number)
(ɫ’)        - Monadic function:
 ɫ            - Call this link as a monad
  ’           - And increment
       ᴘ    Take the product
```

Comment: I'm looking forward to yuno becoming more usable!

Answer (score 8):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 13 bytes

```apl
¯1+(≡+×/)⍥1⍣≡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//9B6Q22NR50LtQ9P19d81LvU8FHvYiD3f9qjtgmPevsedTUfWm/8qG3io76pwUHOQDLEwzP4v4mBgq1CmgKQ6xXs76egHm2kowBBprHqXMZoksZAMRMzTB0wbBobC1RhZmFoiqbGFCIPROaxCOUwLUA9libG5mh6YBrgWiHIGGQGSIupkYW5oSUWTXCj4TqNY2MxTYEaFKsOAA)

Takes a nested APL array (which can be obtained from JSON-converting the test cases) and returns the original number.

#### How it works

This uses the Depth operator `f⍥n`, which hasn't made into mainstream yet. A depth-1 value in a mixed array can be a vector or a scalar (if one of its siblings is nested). `≡+×/` is an expression that keeps scalar intact (product is itself and its depth `≡` is 0), and evaluates product + 1 for vectors. Now, we can simply repeat this at depth 1 until the entire value becomes a single number, and subtract 1 at the end (to negate the +1 applied at the very last layer).

Comment: I don't think this answer can be ported to J, but I'd appreciate any ideas you have on improving my answer.  It felt like it _should_ be much simpler, but given the way J's `L:` and `L.` verbs work, and the requirements for cases like `[ x x ]` and `[[ x x ]]`, things got ugly.

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>22</s> 17 bytes

```
1+1##&@@#&//@#-1&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVNNi9swEL3rVwSn5FKHtTSWJRESXOgeeivd3oQOJnhbQTYOWRcWQn57Kku2PlwXHKKPeW9m3jy9Nf3v9q3p9bF5vO4f@DNerzd1vd48PdXrLd48vnYS3XTe3fcnfW53SO9/ds8fl2v7/q67c/3SX/X514/2cmqOrbxlMtsesluWZ2pY3LO7qvUOdSmo26HvBtbL11rv912utwezUii/DTlyx/n80V@bYy8/vRyv@tJ/O1/@9O4mz5Ah/3I65dlqe1i5tbqrhyT5yn1UDTdlgeR4BsqeYHAnMITYE8BIgluh8QYmvCjs0fQzCEdbOZKRAWOfhblA/xkmNoJECQwllyTKVPIiukxpRjwlvpiR2W3ANjf2IsqoiXk2YqsZAnnBDRv1IUyFLqdObWDFMfWBY3CscgRxn5qQnJQCDDYpxdbqdizhjHMCZ4QJJIMKNKQCu5MzbTFhg7pJCyGpUv@OZURbOCWcYZEOh01CLLQdeJSfDUA1Ux4CmsblTEXzQlSUe@uQWKeov@XEUXOBOPjBQuc6hNkujROUHx1QjKGozF9lDFUKawAWJ5Cz4YcJxnuWmiopYamxoB1NMvl34L1VYMBATY0UoBhctuD5yGuQOntOvvBUIHU2iwQl/3NGpCARhIJ5AVRgXFWY/wU)

```
1+1##&@@#&//@#      expressions become the product of their arguments plus 1
              -1&   subtract 1 (outermost list doesn't increment)
```

Comment: so beautiful! +1

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 35 bytes

```javascript
f=a=>a.map(n=>p*=+n||f(n)+1,p=1)&&p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVRNj5swEL3zKzjt2t0EYQ/Gtlbm1ksP7aFHirQoTVqqLKAERSt1@9tTMMYflEpG4PG8@XjzzK/6Vl8Pl6Yf9m33/Xi/n1Stijp5rXvUqqL/oJ7a9/cTavET2fWK4IeH/j6ol6iku3herIr3RZylUWlsUGkLgdkCk4u2AIlKmL8icwILXqbatDwjYg6bz0FMBEJsFj472jVG4gYkM@BRcEi9TJlIvcMwjMEzaosxkecN6OZMLzLzmlhno7qayVGkYozGrAuvXJdLp9oxF4RZR@Pss@xB5lUtSEEzCSM2KEXXOu94ENPPCYJTLqPSscBcKtC7csUtoXxiN2jBJa2qf8di0BrOqOBEhsPhCxEbbbs4lZ0NQL5iHhya@eUsRYtU5kxY6VCfJ6@/7cRecy6w04OGrnlws90aJ1R2dMAIgTQfX/koqExqAXA/Qbkavpugv@ehqIISthpz3LEgk70HVlspAQJsrJEBpJPKNjTvaQ1CZa@Db1wVCJXNPULp/5ThMUglZTDeACYJyXMiopdkuDSvCCfX/twM6PFb@4j1/@wtVkX8tpj3hTHfJvOnr18@J319uR7RDWP8HA3Jqbt8rA8/ESqbXdxVeHL7HcXxoWuv3fmYnLsf6IQarFS3m94j6A9@vv8F)

Comment: You can save 1 byte by using `|` instead of `&&`.

Comment: @HKboy but it failed on last 3 test cases.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (`-p`), 30 bytes

```perl
y/,]/*)/;s/\[/(1+/g;$_=-1+eval
```

replacing `[` , `,`, `]` with `(1+`, `*`, `)` resp., and evaluating.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVPLTsMwELznK3rIodCm9nrjF1HhC/iCYFUcCkKqaEUREj9PcGzHjxAkV43tndnd2fHl@HHiw5WsmvvVend7Q0hXH/c1dMM32RpiD7oreerJGjbktasP@wY2x6/n0zB@28h9fXg4370MPduu/OJm5Gpp1YczNO4E0J/gGOJOEKoe/VcVbnDCa@qOpp9FeFrhSQIDQMwifWBclkkGkG5RVsUlyzK1imaXJU3AcxaLCcx@g6650Itusybm2ZirZgxUVFk2HkOkSV1OnbpAoYDHwBCcq5xB/DITUrFWo8UWpbha/U4WnHlOVJJJXfVJBZ5Sodv1M22ByVHdooWU1Ji/YwloB@dMSdDlcOQkxELbicfE2SCKmfKY0DwvZypaUS24itZhuU5Zf8uJs@YScfKDg851SLNdGieaODrkAEiF/RPWUK12BpB5gn42/DTBfC9LUxUlLDWWtONFpvgOorcoICC3NXJEOrpswfOZ17B09px84alg6WyZCcr@c0amINOMo30BXAMIAernfPl8O79fh@aR7ygMzenyCw)

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 42 bytes

```perl
sub f{my$r=1;map$r*=@$_?1+f(@$_):$_,@_;$r}
```

with a recursive function

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVPbbsIwDH3vV/ShD8Bg1HHTJKAC/1FVFZNAQoKByjZpQvz6ujRJc@k6Kb3EsY/t45PboTnTtr1/vsXHx@U7aQpYX/a3pJkVu6TewstxIr/TVVLPd/U6aZ5tUhfS9jh87c8JPKdFkZDtdXWMT8fl5HU2XWy697ItyTzWi1bxYhNnaVQaG1bKAqgt2LkoC0JUov6LzAn28SJVpv6RERo21yAGAcBmYdrRLonETJDIkEXBIfEyZTz1DkMYE0@JLcYg6w2q5kwvIvOaGGYjqprOkadcolHrwirXZd@pcsw5UOtonH2WvRC9qj6Sk0ygjA1KUbXqHQsw/ZzIGWEiKh0L1KVCtSsH3AJhHbtBCy5pVf0di4lW4ZRwBiIcDuuJGGnb4VR2Noj5gHl00dQvpy@apyKn3EqH@Dx5/Y0n9ppzwE4PKnTIg5vt2DixsqNDCoBpLj@5FFQmlACYn6AcDN9N0N@zUFRBCWONOe5okMneA6utFBCQyhopYtqpbETzntYwVPYQfOSqYKhs5hFK/lOGxyARhKK8AVQA5Dnwn@vt43R9v7eL8@0X)

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>46</sup> 45 bytes

```
[:(*>:)/[:;L:1^:_[:*/L:0;~&1^:((1=#)*1<L.)L:2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYzBTsMwEETv@YoRSDSOihsnBVTH4QASJ6sHrhGgpjiNIThV7Eqc@PXgxCAhDrvSvpm3b@MZXTQoORZYIgX3c0lx/ygfxorHyS0nq4oXkrNn/lLxZCV5Wnxd@CuOWXlOEiYkJZJnI4nqkqKAwPaOolXdUQ1o@gEfu3dtDjDKOvWKuv/0u9PW2ch55J0nb8VlQ2axU42bStj3xu20sdDmeHJLDPrQ/ksmH4Oyp85Fkdq3PXIWoBDIkOMq0E36Q2foMQJfXweeoZ5HZL9Gzjbrv9nk3YSGfzB@Aw)

I thought this was going to be like 10 chars...

Comment: maybe Bubbler's solution would help with shortening this.

Comment: @Razetime I don't see a way, but I asked him for ideas.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
ß‘µ¹ŒḊ?€P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///w/EcNMw5tPbTz6KSHO7rsHzWtCfj//3@0kY6CMRiBWBAE4sdCBKDiIGwaG4sqaISmDSoUi6RFR8EciGD64AahcMF6wAAA)

```
ß‘µPŒḊ?€P      Main Link
       €       For each element:
      ?        - If
    ŒḊ           - It has depth (isn't a number)
ß‘µ            - Call this link on the sub-list, take the product, and increment it
   P           - Otherwise, take the product (or first element, or sum, w/e)
        P      Take the product
```

Answer (score 2):

## MMIX, 56 bytes (14 instrs)

```
typedef union _rpe {
    struct {
        uint64_t flag : 1; // must be 1
        uint64_t val : 63;
    };
    union _rpe *list;
} rpe;

uint64_t __mmixware rpd(rpe encoded);
```

Lists terminate on a `union _rpe` that isn't a list (`flag` is on) whose `val` is 0. (MMIX pointers must be positive for user programs, or a trap occurs.)

```
00000000: 48000003 ec008000 f8010000 fe010004  H¡¡¤ġ¡⁰¡ẏ¢¡¡“¢¡¥
00000010: e3020001 8f040000 e7000008 f303fff9  ẉ£¡¢Ɓ¥¡¡ḃ¡¡®ṙ¤”ż
00000020: 42030003 1a020203 f1fffffb f6040001  B¤¡¤ȷ££¤ȯ””»ẇ¥¡¢
00000030: 23000201 f8010000                    #¡£¢ẏ¢¡¡
```

```
rpd     BNN   $0,0F     // if(encoded.flag)
        ANDNH $0,#8000
        POP   1,0       // return encoded.val;
0H      GET   $1,rJ
        SET   $2,1      // uint64_t i = 1;
0H      LDOU  $4,$0     // loop: rpe n = *encoded.list;
        INCL  $0,8      // encoded++;
        PUSHJ $3,rpd    // uint64_t j = rpd(n);
        BZ    $3,0F     // if(!j) goto end;
        MULU  $2,$2,$3  // i *= j;
        JMP   0B        // goto loop;
0H      PUT   rJ,$1
        ADDU  $0,$2,1
        POP   1,0       // return i + 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
â╥¡░Ω↕¬∟oqFµ+
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=83d2adb0ea12aa1c6f7146e62b&i=%5B2,+2,+2,+5%5D+%0A%5B%5B2,+2,+3%5D%5D+%0A%5B%5B2,+3,+5%5D%5D+%0A%5B3%5D+%0A%5B2,+3,+3,+5%5D+%0A%5B2,+%5B2,+%5B2,+5%5D%5D%5D+%0A%5B%5B2,+5%5D%5D+%0A%5B%5B2,+2,+7,+%5B2,+2,+2,+2,+3,+7%5D%5D%5D+%0A%5B2,+2,+2,+2,+2,+3,+5%5D+%0A%5B2,+2,+2,+7,+%5B2,+2,+2,+2%5D%5D+%0A%5B2,+%5B2,+2,+3,+7,+%5B2,+3,+3%5D%5D%5D+%0A%5B2,+3,+3,+%5B2,+2,+2,+2,+2,+2,+7%5D%5D+%0A%5B5,+%5B2,+2,+7%5D,+%5B2,+%5B2,+%5B2,+5%5D%5D%5D%5D+%0A%5B5,+%5B2,+%5B2,+2,+%5B2,+2,+2,+5%5D,+%5B2,+%5B2,+5,+5,+5%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D+%0A%5B3,+3,+%5B2,+2,+3,+3%5D,+%5B2,+7,+%5B2,+%5B2,+2,+2,+5%5D%5D%5D%5D+%0A%5B7,+%5B2,+2,+5,+5%5D,+%5B2,+3,+5,+%5B2,+3,+7%5D%5D%5D+%0A%5B%5B2,+%5B2,+%5B2,+5,+%5B2,+2,+3%5D%5D,+%5B2,+2,+2,+2,+3,+3,+7%5D%5D%5D%5D+%0A%5B2,+2,+2,+2,+7,+%5B2,+5%5D,+%5B2,+2,+%5B2,+2,+2,+2,+2,+2,+3%5D%5D%5D+%0A%5B2,+3,+3,+%5B2,+3,+5%5D,+%5B2,+5,+5,+%5B2,+2,+7%5D%5D%5D+%0A%5B%5B2,+2,+2,+3,+%5B2,+2,+%5B2,+3,+7%5D%5D%5D,+%5B2,+2,+2,+2,+2,+2,+3,+%5B2,+2,+3%5D,+%5B2,+2,+7,+%5B2,+3,+3,+7%5D%5D,+%5B2,+5,+%5B2,+2,+2,+%5B2,+5%5D%5D,+%5B2,+%5B2,+2,+%5B2,+2,+3%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D+%0A%5B5,+7,+7,+%5B2,+3,+%5B2,+5%5D,+%5B2,+%5B2,+2,+2,+5%5D%5D%5D,+%5B2,+2,+2,+7,+%5B2,+%5B2,+%5B2,+2,+2,+%5B2,+5%5D%5D%5D%5D,+%5B2,+2,+2,+2,+2,+3,+3,+%5B2,+5,+%5B2,+3,+%5B2,+2,+2,+2%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D+%0A%5B2,+3,+3,+%5B2,+2,+2,+3,+3%5D,+%5B2,+3,+%5B2,+%5B2,+5%5D%5D%5D,+%5B2,+3,+%5B2,+2,+3,+%5B2,+2,+2,+2,+2,+3%5D,+%5B2,+%5B2,+5,+7,+7%5D%5D,+%5B2,+2,+%5B2,+5%5D,+%5B2,+2,+%5B2,+2,+3%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D+%0A&m=2)

recursion's a bit clunky here, but thankfully it works.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 41 bytes

```ruby
f=->n{n.map{|x|x*0==0?x:f[x]+1}.reduce:*}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVPLasMwELz7Kwy9pW3Qaq1XwO2HGB36SG4NIRBwSfLtrqy3FBVkjJbdmd3Z0fny@bssh/H17Xg9bn8@TtfbfJs3ZBzJ@7w7TLN@hvv2vP@@fO13m/ty6g/TRF96d5jW/VM/kM6GfRy1jQKmKNrUNYrgouhuXcDDkGSiisRw@NZqS8UTqEcEKNiFK4jHoApfrAYUXTlAzPGTSFIllHAeh9GiQc/iLugEcLOqoRqwZqauO5MsifSoLKYJnRSIKqzJXAIrkn1BvpmszB0dqiUdFPr6oi3bu7uJAjfnRimoUK46qcMSJdrbVGkPVAT1i5ESudaPqwsIKwSjUoB6XKAI4jRkSFg67g6RN7aCCYHlbYUBJFGcycJqNNcum7fdQDZoAk@esaW1JmnvrTWjjitFBoCEmx83phtUNIfISabKGGmz@V2UpivaaA2XNGQFU3ozUUJAQGb6ZIgkOLDxNjIfYun@mqDxpLB0vsiEpf85JVOSKsrQvBCmADgH2S1/)

Comment: [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##dVPbasMwDH3PVwT21l2wrPg26PohwQ8drE9bKYWNjLbfniW@y/XAIVhI50hHx@fv9995Pmyf346Xj5/9Z398@dqfLtfpOm3Ydst20@thnOwj3Da7zW0@9Ydx5E@9P8La/qEfWOfCIY7WRQFzFF3qGkXwUfS3LuJhTFqihqVw/NZqRyUzaEAEIOzKF6SzoKpQbAZUHR0g5YRJNKsSKFzAEZw0GFj8Bb0AflYzVAPWzNx3tyRrpgOqSGnKZgWSCmuy1CBIcigoN1OU@WNjteaDwVBP2nK9@5siuCU3asWV8dVZHZEp0d3GSnvgKqpPRsrk1t6vLiKsEIJrBeZ@gSqK05AhY9m0O0TZ2ApmBFG2FQfQzEihidV4qV0xb7uBYtAMnj3jSmtN8t5ba0abVooCAJlcfnIx3WCSOVRJMlbGyJst74qajrTRGi5rKAhTfjNJQkBAsfQpEFl0YONtFD5E6v6aoPGkkDpfFcLy/5xSKMkNF7i8EGEApATdzX8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 34 bytes

```
~(`, 
$*
^.
.+¶$$.(
\[
$$.(_
]
$*)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVIxDsIwDNzzig5FKlBVolaUJ/CIYCgDAwsDYuZZPICPhTRxYyekUqrWjX13Pvt5e90f14PbdMfJvbupb1S7U@dBDfvvp22HTp2smt8Xhf5m65wd@yYejcpSBEjfMP/23@CfGEJM9MHy@ATK1sgQJl6m4@tMSJQ/R4lXq0OmIowYQNAoRZW4Y@BTVqcrg6x50c0JlCTtEKnxYKzICIOSGJkMiRm4Jc2wECIrncnEMQHiv5VUU9hplsYq7XD1v2/ANVpSs6xELHBJQ51EyGc4nl0oLTvludRGAohpYEaC2WJY7L2MTT78jK7WBLujM6a0mLi2f2IjIN@2EqiytpBvnRFGjWvTJWd@) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
, 
$*
```

Change all separators into multiplication operators.

```
^.
.+¶$$.(
```

Change the opening `[` into code to replace the input with the product of the values.

```
\[
$$.(_
```

Change the remaining `[`s into code to increment the product of the values.

```
]
$*)
```

Change the `]`s into code to terminate the product expressions.

```
~(`
```

Evaluate the resulting program on the original input.

For example, the input `[2, 2, 2, 7, [2, 2, 2, 2]]` is transformed into the following Retina program:

```
.+
$.(2*2*2*7*$.(_2*2*2*2*))
```

The `2*2*2*2*` evaluates to `________________`, so the `$.(_)` results in `17`, and the outer multiplication then produces the final result of 952.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ËÉªßD)ÄÃ×
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=y8mq30QpxMPX&input=WzIsIDMsIDMsIFsyLCAyLCAyLCAzLCAzXSwgWzIsIDMsIFsyLCBbMiwgNV1dXSwgWzIsIDMsIFsyLCAyLCAzLCBbMiwgMiwgMiwgMiwgMiwgM10sIFsyLCBbMiwgNSwgNywgN11dLCBbMiwgMiwgWzIsIDVdLCBbMiwgMiwgWzIsIDIsIDNdXV1dXV0) or [test 2-25](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=y8mq30QpxMPX&input=WwpbMl0KWzNdClsyLCAyXQpbNV0KWzIsIDNdCls3XQpbMiwgMiwgMl0KWzMsIDNdClsyLCA1XQpbWzIsIDVdXQpbMiwgMiwgM10KW1syLCAyLCAzXV0KWzIsIDddClszLCA1XQpbMiwgMiwgMiwgMl0KW1syLCAyLCAyLCAyXV0KWzIsIDMsIDNdCltbMiwgMywgM11dClsyLCAyLCA1XQpbMywgN10KWzIsIFsyLCA1XV0KW1syLCBbMiwgNV1dXQpbMiwgMiwgMiwgM10KWzUsIDVdCl0tbVI) or [run all test cases](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=y8mq30QpxMPX&input=WwpbMiwgMiwgMiwgNV0KW1syLCAyLCAzXV0KW1syLCAzLCA1XV0KWzNdClsyLCAzLCAzLCA1XQpbMiwgWzIsIFsyLCA1XV1dCltbMiwgNV1dCltbMiwgMiwgNywgWzIsIDIsIDIsIDIsIDMsIDddXV0KWzIsIDIsIDIsIDIsIDIsIDMsIDVdClsyLCAyLCAyLCA3LCBbMiwgMiwgMiwgMl1dClsyLCBbMiwgMiwgMywgNywgWzIsIDMsIDNdXV0KWzIsIDMsIDMsIFsyLCAyLCAyLCAyLCAyLCAyLCA3XV0KWzUsIFsyLCAyLCA3XSwgWzIsIFsyLCBbMiwgNV1dXV0KWzUsIFsyLCBbMiwgMiwgWzIsIDIsIDIsIDVdLCBbMiwgWzIsIDUsIDUsIDVdXV1dXQpbMywgMywgWzIsIDIsIDMsIDNdLCBbMiwgNywgWzIsIFsyLCAyLCAyLCA1XV1dXQpbNywgWzIsIDIsIDUsIDVdLCBbMiwgMywgNSwgWzIsIDMsIDddXV0KW1syLCBbMiwgWzIsIDUsIFsyLCAyLCAzXV0sIFsyLCAyLCAyLCAyLCAzLCAzLCA3XV1dXQpbMiwgMiwgMiwgMiwgNywgWzIsIDVdLCBbMiwgMiwgWzIsIDIsIDIsIDIsIDIsIDIsIDNdXV0KWzIsIDMsIDMsIFsyLCAzLCA1XSwgWzIsIDUsIDUsIFsyLCAyLCA3XV1dCltbMiwgMiwgMiwgMywgWzIsIDIsIFsyLCAzLCA3XV1dLCBbMiwgMiwgMiwgMiwgMiwgMiwgMywgWzIsIDIsIDNdLCBbMiwgMiwgNywgWzIsIDMsIDMsIDddXSwgWzIsIDUsIFsyLCAyLCAyLCBbMiwgNV1dLCBbMiwgWzIsIDIsIFsyLCAyLCAzXV1dXV1dCls1LCA3LCA3LCBbMiwgMywgWzIsIDVdLCBbMiwgWzIsIDIsIDIsIDVdXV0sIFsyLCAyLCAyLCA3LCBbMiwgWzIsIFsyLCAyLCAyLCBbMiwgNV1dXV0sIFsyLCAyLCAyLCAyLCAyLCAzLCAzLCBbMiwgNSwgWzIsIDMsIFsyLCAyLCAyLCAyXV1dXV1dClsyLCAzLCAzLCBbMiwgMiwgMiwgMywgM10sIFsyLCAzLCBbMiwgWzIsIDVdXV0sIFsyLCAzLCBbMiwgMiwgMywgWzIsIDIsIDIsIDIsIDIsIDNdLCBbMiwgWzIsIDUsIDcsIDddXSwgWzIsIDIsIFsyLCA1XSwgWzIsIDIsIFsyLCAyLCAzXV1dXV1dCl0tbVI)

Takes advantage of the fact that the sub-arrays are never singletons.

```
ËÉªßD)ÄÃ×     :Implicit input of array
Ë             :Map each D
 É            :  Subtract 1 (resulting in NaN if it's an array)
  ª           :  Logical OR with
   ßD         :  A recursive call with argument D
     )        :  Group that together
      Ä       :  Add 1 to the result
       Ã      :End map
        ×     :Reduce by multiplication
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>65</s> 57 bytes

```r
r=function(l,z=0)`if`(is.list(l),prod(sapply(l,r,1))+z,l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVTLasMwELz7Kwy9WNQtktZ6HdJvSUkbCJgk2M6h@fnU9UuvlRoQmCij2dmd3e0e3ffhcu6H7nYYdo9ud7ydD8Ppcq7a@r6jZH867qtT/96e@qFqSX3tLl9V/3m9tj8joqsZIa/3uiUuTTWBeV3ORxBSvpRvH2VDiwjlQIGsQAZpIEyECxBYDITtzwLTBCvFDDIURYXfv5BrFjItzipjLJurstTbGWUpG8Y0oIp0UbcntrqaZvBxQBtJ8GwNFmn2AmavNg9Mk6k0JpvPmc7vNdVIfOG9VCS2xLNm4ZKaiSyXwxk2KcI8H@IE0LwxgISIcp1qZG8UKiFQD1pxZWJy3zvhi4Xpxvnl9hDjCuuiZCn9FAjBu3QNskQRXCtm8r2qXL8yNtgwxO1PAPlEi4FPLsKEnMpoaqTQ2RHloaVBjdPSgyr6GvwxmqhSBvhN/l8TA3EbFQRjQOX4keN8NgadChXqwTyK@zW8U@nhjLJI1c13UqCq7OJyjWTAQIypCgCKjWZiEwUDCvhiSelILDbAt4gKbObPTIPvJzdcwLh9hGFMSqaL4vEL)

Recursively adds 1 to the product of all list elements.

This would end-up one-too-many, so we skip adding 1 for the outermost loop.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 33 bytes

```
ＦＳ≡ι[⊞υ¹]¿⊖Ｌυ⊞υ×⊕⊟υ⊟υＩυ¿Σι⊞υ×⊟υΣι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU49C8IwEN39FYdTAnHQIoIddREcCnULHUK82kD6QZPoIP72GJtqi@GGvHfv42QletkK7X3Z9kBOTedsbnvV3AilYB7KygqIovBcSGEQlny5h8yZijgGa5qObBFYVQI5ouyxxsbilZyxudmgoyHo67ioGk1omVRZ230kDMYPTQF1iMzCDZYchLEfNl1csRRO21iTuzrc9B8bExiM22B6ec853zCIkzAYAY9oVxTFj5vPpEwmwe7ni9YIt/OAgfhuZl1DUHx@dddv) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＦＳ≡ι
```

Loop over and switch on the input characters.

```
[⊞υ¹
```

For `[` push a `1` to the predefined empty list.

```
]¿⊖Ｌυ
```

For `]` if the list has more than one element, then...

```
⊞υ×⊕⊟υ⊟υ
```

... increment the top element and multiply the second element by it, otherwise...

```
Ｉυ
```

... print the result.

```
¿Σι⊞υ×⊟υΣι
```

Otherwise for digits multiply the top element by the value of the digits.

Comment: "*if the list has more than one element*" - could you save anything there with the knowledge that sub-lists will always have more than one element? Or does that statement apply to the top-level list, too?

Comment: @Shaggy I'm referring to the predefined empty list that I'm using as a stack to know how deep in `[`s I am, rather than the input "list" between the `[` and `]`.

Comment: Ah, I get it now :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), <s>14</s> 12 bytes

Defines a function which takes a nested list and returns an integer.

```
⟨::C⟨←)⟩¿⟩¦Π
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVI7jgIxDL1KWgqaWFEkChqOEbmgWCE6uAEVNfSs2Aqxp1hpD8AhcpEhjj9JAGUmk9jPz/bzbNbb9TTl632xWJU9H0@zfP39/6Pt9viZvsi1y4eLmy9dPnzv8vG8r84pJe9oBXR8BOQTFFM5QXnpAhXh5SkuRgXUuOiEidCx@vXuLXoEojLWEMkjkZSxI/BE6VJgW3wpRT3V2TXEAFrIKGOlRHSKFmZMUl8QhlI6f6L2rLRNrtYmwzpT5BqH0gQ8dqoSBWdNmrZey06fxDUviFmlZM2sVJVrVAoQVcGokamTT5UZxtdcbQJ9OWBpoZs2vs9W5wDDj9U6GmjbRKO25t/klX7wCQ)

```python
⟨        ⟩¦     # map over each element in the input
 ::             # two copies of the TOS
   C            # compare for two ints (0), count occurences for two lists (1)
    ⟨  ⟩¿       # if the TOS is truthy:
     ←)         #   recursively call the function and add 1
           Π    # after the map: take the product
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 37 bytes

```
f(a)=vecprod([if(#b',f(b)+1,b)|b<-a])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVTbaoQwEP0V2T40Un1oBslL2x8J8xDbWoTSBlkKhf13NzExM4kRouxkzpwzN9eaZe6/7LpOwrSvf5/vdvn9EHqexMP42E1ibJ@eu7G9jS@9wXY11n7/C9P0b41d5p@r@3nxxqXx8W3XaC27JpwByQTcDfAOb4B/hQuIYEmPw@wRAzIiFdzpuFAVoPxWZpy1SGR6kYbSSYQht5Jabprufkg@VUmfISKq6M2ODQdjSKa5ZRMslVExDSpsIGLYLJ11KEuQJA7dgxRUetReXaUkCq@0j01j4OIss6TNmE@nmyGBAIoLK8SyWBpPbTCASHNTnE0XM6MJVFYsB/F1OJYAWYZQ7CiebiJbDDh8NbJYoYNuvn2KtUqeTTj2xv0H3AE)